# Php sessions go blank

Tags: php

I have been programming in php on and off for a long long time and i have never seen this strange problem. Every time i add session_start (); to the top of my page it goes blank. I have checked for any blank spaces and tryed it on one line and 3 lines with no success. 
I did install a new freebsd 10.3 server with apache 2.4 and using php 5.6.3. The same code worked fine in older server and what i seen there is no need to worry about enabling sessions. But looking at phpinfo there is no mention of sessions. At this point I am just plan lost.
I have tried all the things listed i have found but still no luck. With phpinfo there no listing for sessions and looked up how to enable sessions and tryied that with mo luck`<?php session_start (); ?>`

Comment: Blank page => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and provide a code example. There isn't much we can do here, sorry.

Comment: I have found all these explanations and explored all of them and no resolution and that is why i am asking again this questions because none of these works

Comment: You need to check your server's logs. A blank page in PHP 99.9999% of the time means there's an error sitting in a log *somewhere* with the details of the error.

Comment: The only error is a falal in php

Comment: @HarryRorarius Yes, you'll need to fix that fatal error, as it's why your screen is blank.

Comment: I dont how to fix this problem

Comment: @HarryRorarius Then maybe you should share the error message with us?

Comment: Ok spent a lot of time and rebuilt the server from scratch because was not sure if it was built right in the first place. The error is fatel error at line 5 which is where session_start () is located. And when i use phpinfo there is not a heading that reference sessions being enabled or disabled no reference at all to sessions